# Get detailed error report ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, dns

I am wanting to receive a more detailed response on a domain through ajax.

Currently I have the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: domain,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        //Set an empty response to see the error
        xml: "<response></response>"   
    },
    datatype: 'application/json',
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    } 
});
```

For example if I have a URL that does 'not exist' I get the error report:

> 0

And if I have a URL that is behind a redirect I get the error report:

> 0

But these are completely different issues.

And I am sure there are many other examples.

I am doing this to test whether DNS settings have been put in place. As with the second case the DNS settings could be working but there is just a redirect on that domain?

Comment: What is `textStatus`?

Comment: There's no `datatype` option to `$.ajax`, the option is `dataType`. And it should be `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: Add the "error : function", this answer shows how = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787722/how-to-extract-text-from-a-html-element-by-id-and-assign-to-a-php-variable/30788293#30788293

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the error callback function from Ajax?

Refer to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for this method.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to change it to

```
$.ajax({
    url: domain,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        //Set an empty response to see the error
        xml: "<response></response>"   
    },
    datatype: 'application/json'
})
.done(function (data) {
    //  process response data here...
})
.fail(function (xhr, error, thrownError) {
    //  process error here...
    console.log(xhr, error, thrownError);
});
```

it perfectly works for me and provide all detailed information that I need